# After migrating the server, My website not working correctly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Before migrating my server, I have taken the database backup and code backup. After migrating the server I added WordPress code and uploaded the database in the PHPMyAdmin.

Now While accessing my domain, It was asking for an update to the database then I updated that.
Now when I am checking the website then I am getting only below image.

[image]

I logged in to the admin panel and

1. Activated my theme,
2. Updated Plugins,
3. Updated Permalinks

then again check my website then I am getting the same issue.

I checked my media then I am getting like the below image.
[image]

Then I checked my custom post, It's showing empty,
Check my all the pages that also showing empty,
Widget is also clear,

I checked my style.css and function.php file and it's showing my code. Even data is also available in the database.

Any other idea what Is the issue?

Comment: Do you still have access to the old WP? Try to use this plugin  https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: @Orbital, No, Now, I don't have an access.

Comment: Not all data is stored in the database. Pictures are stored in the wp-content/uploads folder. Is there no way you can access the old WP again ?

Comment: Try manual install all  plugins that you had on your old site. From the screenshot look like you had the wpbakery page builder plugin. Maybe after installing it the design will come back

Comment: @Orbital, When I uploaded the code on the server the I checked my website it is not working. Then I log in to my account and checked my all the plugins were defective